# Excel auto update value in child list based on parent list

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I am trying to deal with drop down list problem in excel. I need to keep values in cell "B2" correspond with value in "A2" in every moment. So i need to figure out how to autoupdate value in "B2" on change value in "A2".

[image: cell "A2" is filled by range seller and cell "B2" by ranges bmw,mercedes and honda]

[image: A1:A3 range "seller", C2:C3 range "bmw", D2:D3 range "honda" and E2:E3 range "mercedes"]

Data validations in cells:

Cell "A2" = `seller`

Cell "B2" = `=INDIRECT($A$2)`

Problem is that when I pick for example mercedes -> A class and afterwards I change mercedes on honda in cell "B2" is value still A class. I want to show in cell "B2" any of correct values for honda immediately on change in "A2".

Is it possible to update these value with any formula or use macro?

Many thanks for advice.

Comment: I think you're looking for dependent drop downs? http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Comment: The link provided by @TimWilkinson will solve your problem. If need help yet let us know.

Comment: Thank you both for answer. However my problem is not solved in this link. Maybe adjusting solution in last chapter "Clear Dependent Cell After Selecting" I can make my problem fix. Maybe I don't explain it well. So if you take a look on last chapter in link by @TimWilkinson. Instead of clearing dependent cell I need to fill it by any correct value from dependent range. To explain, if i have picked "mercedes" in parent cell and "A class" in depend. cell. Now I pick "bmw" in parent cell and i want to auto update value in depend. cell based on this change. Without changing depend. cell manually

Comment: But how do you know what it should change too? If you but BMW in `A2`, should `B2` show M3 or M5?

Comment: Yes exactly and keep option to select one of these two(M3,M5) manually in list after show one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sort of a workaround. In cell C2 I put this formula to check if B2 has an option from the correct range based on A2:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,INDIRECT(A2),1,FALSE)),HLOOKUP(A2,D1:F3,2,FALSE),B2)
```

Then, I created a macro:

[image]

```
    Sub Change_Model()
'
' Change_Model Macro
'

'
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

And then put this in the Worksheet code:

[image]

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Range("A2")
        Case "BMW": Change_Model
        Case "Honda": Change_Model
        Case "Mercedes": Change_Model
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

This activates the macro anytime you change A2, and then pastes the current calue from C2, into B2, which will always be the first option in the current Seller list.

[image]

Comment: Thank a lot @JacobEdmond. This solved my problem completely :).

Comment: Great! Would you mind selecting this as an answer to your question? Thanks!